# I am using Handlebars, iterating over each arrayItem. Need to get substring and put that value in HTML code

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

{{#each (limit item 12)}

html tag -- img src="http://google.com "alt={{item_name}}.substring(0, 20).concat("...") title={{item_name}}.substring(0, 20).concat("...")

Description  item_name is a attribute inside item. 
Can anyone let me know how to get substring and put it inside html code.

item_name=abcdefhgiadjfaksdjfaksjdflkajsdfkajsdlfjasldkfjalskdjfakjsdfjaskdjfaksldjfasjdfjasdlfjalsdjlakjljdffslfd  Appreciate ur help.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a helper with the Handlebars.registerHelper method:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('shorten', function(longText) {
  return longText.substring(0, 20).concat("...");
});
```

and then use it like this ...

```
{{#each (limit item 12)}

html tag -- img src="http://google.com "alt={{shorten item_name}} title={{shorten item_name}}
```

Comment: if i am using item_name 100 times in my code, should i have to call registerhelper function each and every time.

Comment: No , you register it once. Then you can use it 100 times. One good place to put the registermethod code, would be right above your `Handlebars.compile()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a Handlebars helper function. Something like

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('substring', function(value) {
    return value.substr(0, 20).concat('...');
});
```

Then use it like this in your template:

```
{{substring item_name}}
```

See [Handlebars Documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#helpers) and [Custom Helper Handlebars tutorial](http://jaskokoyn.com/2013/08/08/custom-helpers-handlebars-js-tutorial/)